# Unable to run armeabi-v7a on Android Studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I need to be able to create a virtual device in Android Studio, which allows me to test my app on old Android systems such as Lollipop or Marshmallow, but it looks like I am unable to do it.

The only ARM images I see available are the "armeabi-v7a", and every time I create a new device and try to launch it, I get the error "The emulator process for AVS [device name] has terminated" as shown in the shot below:

[image: Emulator Error]

Everything seems to be in place inside the SKD Tools panel as you can see below:

[image]

And everything works fine with arm64-v8a images.

For your information, I am using Android Studio for Mac version Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 3 which should be the latest one:

[image]

Comment: After a lot of research, it looks like the problem is 32-bit images of the emulated systems. The Android Studio log gives me this error among others: "Emulator: PANIC: Avd's CPU Architecture 'arm' is not supported by the QEMU2 emulator on aarch64 host. " Any ideas where I can find 64-bit Arm images of old Android OSs like Lollipop and such? Or to make the 32-bit images work on my platform?